# How to upgrade Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 to 4.3

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus

It would be great if someone can suggest procedure to update the OS from 4.1.1 to 4.3 (FYI.. my phone does not get automatic update, bought it from South Korea now using in India):

Below are my phone details

```
Phone Model: Galaxy Nexus (maguro)
Android OS version: 4.1.1 (JRO03C.M420KRLB1)
Product Code: yakjukr
Root Access : NO
```

Google has provided factory image matching with my device: [Factory Images "yakju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+)](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#yakjujwr66v)

Can some one please provide details how to update it to 4.3 using above factory image.

B/w though Google has provided all factory images, where does Google tell the installation instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use GNex Toolkit: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392310

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to wait for that! As your phone is not rooted you cannot upgrade your OS yourself.

1. You can root the phone by [Googling it!](http://www.google.com/search?q=rooting%20nexus%20phone%20android)
2. You can wait!
3. You can search for ROMs for your nexus on [XDA-Developers Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com).
4. Best thing about the XDA forums is that you will find method to root your device on the same page on which you will get the ROM for your cell phone!